# CSS in PDF not loading on server

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am using **html2pdf**  library to generate PDF of my HTML. On my local machine below code is working fine but when I deployed the same on the server the PDf is generating without CSS styles. Below is my Code. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("generatePdf").addEventListener("click", () => {
          const cvitae = this.document.getElementById("configuration-area-c");
          var opt = {
            filename: "morsewatchment-configurator.pdf",
            image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
            jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: [12, 6], orientation: "portrait" },
          };
          //html2pdf().from(cvitae).set(opt).save();
        });
      };
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a CSS problem?

Comment: try this `html2canvas: { scale: 2, useCORS: true}`

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Already did no luck. I forgot to mention it here.

Comment: @NicoHaase This is the only code which I am using and to my little knowledge it's a CSS issue because the file is created with the images but without CSS.

Comment: what lib are you using to be specific is it `html2pdf-jspdf2` ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui html2pdf

Comment: could it be related to this issue here on github
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/219

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when working with `html2pdf.js`, you can read more [here](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#issues), also [issue on github](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/219).

The obvious approach to fix this is to include all your needed css rules in a `style` tag directly in the html page.

**Also** you can go to this branch on [Github](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/tree/bugfix/clone-nodes-BUILD)  look into the `/dist/` directory and pull out whichever files your project relies on and use it.

**Or** if you are using `npm` run :

```
 npm install eKoopmans/html2pdf.js#bugfix/clone-nodes-BUILD
```